# Is it possible to run an activity or thread on receiving sms

Tags: android, sms

Is it possible to  Create an activity or thread with service which read incoming message text like if text=ab, start any activity, if text=abc, change audio manger setting,

Answer (score 0):

check this article on [how to handle sms](http://www.apriorit.com/our-company/dev-blog/227-handle-sms-on-android).

in your manifest specify this:

```
    <receiver android:name=".MyActivityIWhantToLaunch" android:exported="true" >
       <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
           <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
       </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```